# White Spaces are removed from string when loading in web view in android

Tags: android, webview

I want to load string in webview , below is the String :-

Hi,

Hw are u ?

Thanks,

When i use loadData of web view it displays the string in single line , spaces are removed.
I want it in same format , hw is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a webview, you should format the string into `html`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you already have a html file., if that is the case you only need put a format in the file.

```
Hi,<br>
Hw are u ?<br>
```